# How to get &curren to display literally, not as an HTML entity

Tags: php, html, url

I'm using php to look at an XML file that has a URL in it. The URLs look something like this:

https://site.com/bacon_report?Id=1&report=1&currentDimension=2&param=1

When I echo out the URLs, the "&curren" shows up as "¤" (AKA #164, A4 or currency symbol) and the links don't work. This happens even though there isn't a closing semicolon for it. What is the cleanest way to make "&curren" display literally?

Comment: You are creating a URL; there are rules you have to follow (url-encoding).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the php function urlencode:

```
urlencode("https://site.com/bacon_report?Id=1&report=1&currentDimension=2&param=1"
```

will output

```
https%3A%2F%2Fsite.com%2Fbacon_report%3FId%3D1%26report%3D1%26currentDimension%3D2%26param%3D1
```

Comment: The link doesnt work anymore if I urlencode the comple url. Its also mentioned here http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/5509/urlencode-of-full-url that one should not do this.

Answer (score 10):

Funny enough I ran into the same problem just now and I found this answer. However, I found another solution which might even be better!

Simply put the variable at the beginning of your query string, and you will avoid the &curren completely.

Do:

```
https://site.com/bacon_report?currentDimension=2&Id=1&report=1&param=1
```

instead of:

```
https://site.com/bacon_report?Id=1&report=1&currentDimension=2&param=1
```

Answer (score 6):

The problem here is escaping - you need to escape the "&" characters. In XML all special characters like <, >, ', " and & should be escaped.

Escape it properly as

```
https://example.com/bacon_report?Id=1&amp;report=1&amp;currentDimension=2&amp;param=1
```

..just like in HTML:

```
<a href="https://example.com/bacon_report?Id=1&report=1&currentDimension=2&param=1">WRONG - no escaping</a>
<a href="https://example.com/bacon_report?Id=1&amp;report=1&amp;currentDimension=2&amp;param=1">CORRECT - correct escape sequence</a>
```

So - the cleanest way to show "&curren" in HTML/XML is to properly escape the ampersand, and render it as "&amp;curren".

Answer (score 0):

I think that in this case it is best to use htmlentities because with urlencode you get 
`https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fbacon_report%3FId%3D1%26report%3D1%26currentDimension%3D2%26param%3D1`

and when applying urldecode, you will still have the &curren symbol
where as with htmlentities the url comes out clean.
`https://example.com/bacon_report?Id=1&report=1&currentDimension=2&param=1`

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue while working on technical documentation (in Markdown which gets converted to HTML).

To solve the issue I used a [zero-width space character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) which I copied and pasted from between these brackets (​). That way it appears that there is no space and can include the below without any issues:
`/search?query=1&currentLonLat=-74.600291,40.360869`

Comment: Adding a zero-width character may look ok, but may screw up the clickable link - then you may in effect change the parameter "currentLonLat" to "%e2%80%8bcurrentLonLat", where "e2%80%8b" is the correctly url encoded zero-width space character.
A better solution would be to correctly encode the special characters, just like in your link `/search?query=1&currentLonLat=-74.600291,40.360869` ...where if you look at the HTML source code it will be encoded as `/search?query=1&amp;currentLonLat=-74.600291,40.360869`, with the ampersand "&" correctly escaped to "&amp;".