# variable name with 'current' word in php adds special character

Tags: php

I am creating a URL to call in PHP.when I use  any variable name as 'current_XX'  the system truncates my variable and adds special character to my URL.The character '¤' is added.It works fine if I use other variable name, like 'curr_XX'.

code :

```
$full_url = $url.
'&permanent_address='.$user_area.
'&permanent_city='.$user_city.
'&permanent_state='.$user_state.
'&permanent_pincode='.$user_pincode.
'&current_address='.$user_area.
'&current_city='.$user_city.
'&current_state='.$user_state.
'&current_pincode='.$user_pincode

echo $full_url;
```

output :
permanent_address=Marathalli&permanent_city=Bangalore&permanent_state=&permanent_pincode=¤t_address=Marathalli¤t_city=Bangalore¤t_state=¤t_pincode=

Comment: Duplicate: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19670380/how-to-get-curren-to-display-literally-not-as-an-html-entity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19670380/how-to-get-curren-to-display-literally-not-as-an-html-entity).

Comment: Thanks Chris..Also I m looking for a reason behind this behaviour.

Comment: I think it's a bug in PHP.  An HTML entity has a format of `&<name>;`.  `&curren;` is a valid entity, whereas `&curren` is not (note the missing semicolon).  PHP wrongly treats `&curren` as an HTML entity.  I'm not aware of any other language that does this.

Comment: Thanks.. :) ..  Also I find the same thing with '&reg'