# http_build_query encode `currency` key to `¤cy=USD`

Tags: php

There is weird behavior of `http_build_query` function. Array

```
Array
(
[merchant_id] => 2005197514857165061
[merchant_site_id] => 144033
[currency] => USD
[total_amount] => 1
)
```

it converts to

```
merchant_id=2005197514857165061&merchant_site_id=144033¤cy=USD&total_amount=1
```

As you can see, instead of `currency` it encodes to `¤cy`

EDIT
code as requested

```
        $postData['merchant_id'] = $this->merchant_id;
        $postData['merchant_site_id'] = $this->merchant_site_id;
        $postData['currency'] = $transaction['currency'];
        $postData['total_amount'] = $transaction['amount'];
        var_dump($postData);

        var_dump(http_build_query($postData));
```

and the output

```
array(4) { ["merchant_id"]=> string(19) "2005197514857165061" ["merchant_site_id"]=> string(6) "144033" ["currency"]=> string(3) "USD" ["total_amount"]=> string(1) "1" } string(83) "merchant_id=2005197514857165061&merchant_site_id=144033¤cy=USD&total_amount=1"
```

Comment: Care to share any actual code?

Comment: Could you please share the output of `var_dump()` instead of `print_r()`?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález check edit please

Comment: It's not encoded like that, only *displayed* like that by your browser. The string is still fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get 83 bytes:

```
string(83) "merchant_id=2005197514857165061&merchant_site_id=144033¤cy=USD&total_amount=1"
```

However, the string shown has only 77 characters, most of which can be safely assumed to be single-byte. That means that you are actually getting `currency` rather than `¤cy`. Thus the straneous `¤` symbol must be the result of some further post-processing.

`var_dump()` output contains line feeds and you've shared it in a single line, what suggests you aren't looking at the generated HTML code but the rendered view. In HTML, `¤` can be encoded as the `&curren;` entity.

For some reason, this entity appears to be treated differently than others:

```html
<p>&curren;cy / &currency</p>
<p>&euro;pe / &europe</p>
```

So if you inject the URL in HTML make sure you encode it:

```
echo htmlspecialchars(http_build_query($postData));
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that when you do the conversion, that only affects when it is in the HTML since the browser interprets & curren as an entity.

If you do it through the terminal, it throws the expected result but if you do it through the browser it really throws the symbol at you.

***You have 2 options:***

1 - You can change the name of the index and receive it in another way in the file.

2 - You can send it in the same way and regardless of what happens, PHP interprets it in the correct way.

> Read this [How to get &curren to display literally, not as an HTML entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19670380/how-to-get-curren-to-display-literally-not-as-an-html-entity/19670462)

This in the result in my console
[image]